# select all tr of a table and send it to the controller using checkbox , in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use the Check box for selecting multiple users and sending the result to my controller.

At first I was only sending the number of mobile users to the controller but it became necessary to send more than the number, I need number and name user, my controller and my view are as follows:

Would somehow send the number and name for example?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Enviar", "Home")) {
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayName("Nome")</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayName("CANCELADO")</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayName("Numero")</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CELULAR" value="@item.CELULAR" />
          </td>
          <td name="Nome">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NOME)</td>
          <td name="Email">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CANCELADO)</td>
          <td name="Celular" value="@item.CELULAR">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CELULAR)</td>
        </tr>
      }
    </tbody>   
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Selecionar"/> 
}
```

The controller that receives:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Enviar(String[] celular) {
   .....
   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When posting collections, you must index them correctly. Therfore, you must use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`.

Also, why does your `HttpPost` take a `String[]` and not your Model? First change that to be your model type.

Assuming your model is: `@model List<YourType>`

Change your `HttpPost` to take that:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Enviar(List<YourType> model) {
   .....
   return View();
}
```

Now we'll rewrite your `foreach` into a `for` and use the `CheckBoxFor` helper. Also, add `HiddenFor` fields for any properties you want to see on post:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].CELULAR)
      </td>
      <td name="Nome">
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].NOME)
          @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].NOME)
      </td>
      <td name="Email">
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].CANCELADO)
          @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].CANCELADO)
      </td>
      <td name="Celular" value="@m[i].CELULAR">
          @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].CELULAR)
      </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: I'm not using to model, would do without using model? the way that I'm in recendo String numbers and all this working out, I wanted to get names and numbers for example, did not want to use a model

Comment: @user2292576 You should really use a model to be doing things like this it is best practice.

Comment: so he did not have a problem selecting this I selected .. any idea how to catch only those who have the check box marked?

Comment: @user2292576 You can check on the `HttpPost` action which items have `CELULAR` set to true. Something like `var selected = model.Where(m => m.CELULAR).ToList()`

Comment: @Thank you..Nice catch..
for each wouldn't work you need a for loop.

Comment: be carefull for count() not count without ().....  u must use
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)

instead of

for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)

Comment: @AhmedSolimanFlasha That's not true, not for a `List`, you do need to do that for an `IEnumerable` though.